# Show list of deleted lines between two revisions

Tags: svn, comparison, diff, revisions

I have two revisions r1 and r2. r1 added different lines to different files(and did other modifications too). r2 deleted some of the lines introduced by r1 from some of the files. Is there any way to get a list of those files from which r2 deleted lines that were introduced by r1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

`svn diff` gives you a unified diff between two revisions. Using the `--summarize` flag lists just the file names.

So, `svn diff -rR1:R2 --summarize` will give a list of all affected files between revisions `R1` and `R2`.

Now, for each of those files, you can use grep to get a list of deleted lines via searching against `"^-"` (ie: lines that begin with the `-` character).

The overall command would be:

```
R1="your first revision value"
R2="your second revision value"
for i in $(svn diff -r${R1}:${R2} --summarize | cut -c9-)
do
   echo "Listing lines deleted between revisions ${R1} and ${R2} in file:${i}"
   echo "===================================================================="
   svn diff -r${R1}:${R2} ${i} | grep -in "^-"
   echo "===================================================================="
done
```

The `cut` command is used to remove the leading status flags and spaces from the output of `svn -diff --summarize`, while the grep command is searching for lines marked as deleted between the revisions. The `-n` argument to grep also tells it to print the line number for the affected change in the diff. This is not the same as the line number in the original file, but it's in the same neighborhood.

Comment: summarize gives a list where the name(path) of modified file is preceded by 'M'. My requirement is more specific.I want those modifications that involved  deleting of line(s) by r2 introduced by r1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of files changed you want to use `svn log` with the `--verbose` flag

[svn manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

eg:

```
svn log -v http://myrepo/files
```